# uwsgi server showing error when performing a flask function that takes upto 6 seconds

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to deploy a Flask application with uwsgi and nginx server. Uwsgi server is throwing a 400 bad request error when the flask function starts. This function takes up to 6 seconds to execute.

flask file

```
    @app.route('/creatingbio', methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def creatingbio():
            if request.method == 'POST':
                result = request.form
                append_questions.append(result)
                return render_template("creatingbio.html",result=result)
    
    
    @app.route("/performing")
    def performing():
        try:
                
                
                dp=dataprocessing() 
                return "DataProcessed"
    
            
                
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return render_template("failure.html",e=e)
    
        
    @app.route("/result", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def result():
        return render_template("result.html")
```

The creating page will wait for the "performing" function to execute and then move to the result page. The "performing" function is not being executed.

uwsgi.ini

```
    [uwsgi]
    module = wsgi:app
    
    master = true
    processes = 5
    
    socket = myproject.sock
    chmod-socket = 660
    vacuum = true
    
    die-on-term = true
```

nginx file

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name your_domain www.your_domain;
    
        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Which one is the creating page? How/where is it invoking the 'performing' function? Where are you redirecting to the 'result' page?